# opencv app with multiple windows - only window with focus gets refreshed constantly

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I'm working on an C++ app which uses opencv for some data manipulation and visualization. I'm using three to four `cvShowImage()` statements to visualize the data. I've recently noticed, that only the window which has focus, will be updated constantly after each `cvShowImage()` call. All the other windows only get updated infrequently. Is there a way to make sure that all opencv windows get refreshed and updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't already, I would suggest issuing a `cvWaitKey(30)` after each `cvShowImage()` and not only once after the last one. Or you could try [displaying all the images in one window](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/DisplayManyImages).

Comment: +1 Since I agree. I've also demonstrated [how to display multiple images here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850436/display-multiple-image-in-same-window-with-opencv/10850609#10850609).